# Seleccionar valor en input de una búsqueda dinámica en php

Tags: php, html, ajax

tengo un input en el que según lo que vaya escribiendo me van apareciendo los resultados de una búsqueda dinámica en una tabla php. El tema está en que funciona perfectamente pero no sé como al hacerle click al elemento me lo coja el input. Para hacerse una idea, yo voy escribiendo en el input lo que quiero buscar en la tabla y me van apareciendo los resultados en un desplegable abajo... cuando veo el elemento que quiero, no sé como darle click y que lo coja el input:

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding-top:20px">
    <input type="text" id="busqueda_u" class="form-control typeahead input-sm tt-input" placeholder="Find a student" autocomplete="off" data-reactid=".0.0.0.0.0.0" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; padding-top:10px">
    <div id="resultado_u" style="position:absolute; background-color:#333; z-index:1"></div>
    </div>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var consulta_u;
        //hacemos focus al campo de búsqueda
        $("#busqueda_u").focus();

        //comprobamos si se pulsa una tecla
        $("#busqueda_u").keyup(function(e){

              //obtenemos el texto introducido en el campo de búsqueda
              consulta_u = $("#busqueda_u").val();
              //hace la búsqueda                                                                                  
              $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "buscar_universidad.php",
                    data: "bu="+consulta_u,
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: function(){
                    //imagen de carga
                    $("#resultado_u").html("<p align='center'><img src='images/loader.gif' width='20px' /></p>");
                    },
                    error: function(){
                    alert("error petición ajax");
                    },
                    success: function(data){                                                    
                    $("#resultado_u").empty();
                    $("#resultado_u").append(data);                                                             
                    }
              });                                                                         
        });                                                     
});
```

buscar_universidad.php

```
<?php

      $buscar = $_POST['bu'];

      if(!empty($buscar)) {
            buscar($buscar);
      }

      function buscar($bu) {

            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM u_universidades WHERE uni_nombre LIKE '%".$bu."%' LIMIT 10");

            $contar = @mysql_num_rows($sql);

            if($contar == 0){
                  echo "No results for '<b>".$bu."</b>'.";
            }else{
              while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $id = $row['student_id'];  
                $universidad = $row['uni_nombre'];
                $continente = $row['continente'];
                echo $universidad."<br />";
                //echo $nombre." "."<a>".$apellidos."</a>"."<br />";
            }
        }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Estás devolviendo los resultados como un html separado por saltos de línea con los que rellenas un div. Debieras en cambio devolverlo como un conjunto de opciones con las cuales rellenar un elemento `select`

Comment: Gracias por contestar... el select sería ponerlo dentro del buscar_universidad.php?

Comment: no. El div `#resultado_u` debiera ser un select. El backend podría responder con un conjunto de elementos `<option>` pero sería más sano que respondiera con un array en formato json que tú parsearas en el front y a partir de él generases los options dinámicamente

Comment: si no he entendido mal, lo que haces es cada vez que escribes en el input se te genera dinámicamente una tabla diferente y no sabes recoger los valores por ejemplo de una linea de esa tabla generada. Si quieres cada linea generada puede ser un form por si lo quieres hacer por POST o si lo quieres seguir haciendo dinámico al submit le creas una función y ahí metes los valores que has creado.

Comment: tambien le puedes crear un evento al select que creas dinámicamente así cada select tendrá unos datos diferentes, lo de arriba creí que renderizabas una tabla, le pones id al select creado y a ese le creas el evento onclick

Comment: @amenadiel no me funciona cambiando el div por select... sale el simbolo de flecha hacia abajo y no despliega nada. Al escribir en el input no hace nada tampoco

Comment: El select se inicia vacío. Pero si tu backend devuelve un arreglo del tipo `["universidad 1", "universidad 2"]` en el front tienes que parsear ese arreglo, iterar sobre él, y por cada elemento crear un `option` que luego metes en el select haciendo `$('#resultado_u').append(optionelement);`

Comment: Si tu backend devuelve en cambio el html `<option value="universidad 1">universidad 1</option><option value="universidad 2">universidad 2</option>` puedes tratarlo exactamente como lo manejas ahora. De todos modos tienes que cambiar el backend para que no devuelva simplemente texto separado por elementos `br`, que no te sirven para llenar el select

Comment: Finalmente: en tu código veo que tienes aplicada la clase `typeahead` pero no estás usando el plugin `typeahead` que se inicializaría haciendo `$("#busqueda_u").typeahead(...configuracion...)`

Comment: Finalmente después de hora y pico intentándolo no lo hago funcionar... seguiré investigando a ver como lo puedo solucionar... gracias de todas formas